# Finding the critical points of a 2-variable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I want to make sure I know how to find the critical points of a simple 2 variable function:

$f(x,y) = x^3+y^3-3xy$

- $\dfrac{\delta f}{\delta x} = 3x^2-3y$
- $\dfrac{\delta g}{\delta y} = 3y^2-3x$

Now we solve the following system:

$3x^2-3y=0$

$3y^2-3x=0$

$\implies$ x=y

Therefore the critical points are $(-1;1),(-1,-1),(1,-1),(1,1)$

Is that the correct way to do it?

Comment: What is the derivative with respect to $x$ of $x^3$? Same goes for $y^3$. The approach is correct otherwise. For the critical points, you would get $(0, 0), (1, 1)$.

Comment: @Moo Here I've edited it

Comment: From the first, you get $y = x^2$, substitute into the second and you get?

Comment: The standard notation for partial derivatives is $\partial$ instead of $\delta$.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost correct. The only solutions to the system of equations 
$$3x^2-3y=0 \text{ and } 3y^2-3x=0$$

are $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$

Comment: True I went too fast, thank you!